# Listing Level 2 Manager next to each worker for Manager Hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle Database

Have typical one manager to many direct reports down the line

Level 1 Manager (Top Level)
Level 2 Managers  (who report to level 1 manager)
Levels 3-15 etc

Have one table that contains all the employees and has the direct manager in manager column

```
EID Name ManagerEID  
123  J    334  
321  E    555  
433  M    555  
223  N    233  
333  A    664
```

What I want is to have a column in a view or select statement that has the Level 2 manager name (or EID) in another column

```
EID Name ManagerEID  Level2  
123  J    334  ManagerA  
321  E    555  ManagerB  
433  M    555  ManagerB  
223  N    233  ManagerA  
333  A    664  ManagerF
```

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. Do you want to select only Level2?

Answer (score 0):

To confirm, you're looking for a separate column in the result that shows the name (or ID) of the manager at level 2 in your hierarchy, right?

If so, this would be one way of getting that:

```
    select eid
          ,name
          ,managereid
          ,min(case when level = 2 then name end) over (partition by null) level_2_name
    from employee_temp
    connect by prior eid = managereid
    start with eid = <<top_level_manager_id>>
```

Not the most elegant solution -- perhaps other folks have better ideas.  But it does display the level 2 manager name  in a separate column on each row, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: this looks like it will work as well thank you for this i will see which is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the responses, I actually found a solution using connect_by_path

```
select EID,lpad(' ',level*3,' ')||full_name name,LEVEL
"Pathlen",connect_by_root full_name root, 
     sys_connect_by_path(full_name,'|') bosses 
from (select * from emptable where EID <> 'topmanagerEID' )h 
connect by prior EID = mgrEID
start with mgrEID = 'topmanagerEID'
```